# Raise # Not yet implemented in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Lets suppose I have this test:

```
test "checks String1 and String2" do
   expect(String1).to be eq("first test")

   #here i want to raise not implemented because I also will have
    #to check for String2
end
```

How can I raise a `# Not yet implemented in Rspec` error. That normally occures when a test is left blank like this:

```
 test "test1"
 test "test2"
```

Is there some method like `skip`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [exactly something like skip](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/skip-examples).

If you wanted the test suite to not pass until the method is implemented, you could just `fail :not_implemented` or something, as well.